# Replace Names with ID Using (G)AWK

Tags: awk

I would like to anonymize several related files by replacing the names with an id number.

#### Example input

file1:

```
2 simon
4 wesley
5 nikesh
8 sarah
1 jenny
```

file2:

```
3 casey
8 jenny
1 alan
1 jessie
5 gordon
9 bill
1 sue
```

file3

```
4 jack
2 jenny
6 wesley
8 sarah
6 gordon
1 derek
6 sue
1 jessie
2 pritesh
7 bill
```

#### Desired Output

file 1

```
2 user1
4 user2
5 user3
8 user4
1 user5
```

file2:

```
3 user6
8 user5
1 user7
1 user8
5 user9
9 user10
1 user11
```

file3

```
4 user12
2 user5
6 user2
8 user4
6 user9
1 user13
6 user11
1 user8
2 user14
7 user10
```

#### What I have tried

Though I expect the solution involves arrays, I am struggling to get my head around this problem.

Comment: `3 user6` - why? What's the algorithm for matching ID and names?

Comment: The first number is unrelated to user[n]

Users are just numbered in sequence. user6 just refers to the 6th user.

The following user in the file is user5 as this user (name) is a duplicate of the fifth user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
awk '!($2 in a){a[$2] = "user"(++n)} {$2 = a[$2]; print > (FILENAME".anon")}' file1 file2 file3
```

- if key `$2` is not already in array `a`, then add it, with value being the concatenation of string `user` and prefix-incremented variable `++n`
- replace the value of `$2` with its corresponding value from array `a`, then print the result to a new file whose name is the concatenation of the current filename plus some arbitrary suffix

Comment: That appears to do exactly what I was looking for. If you have the time, I would be interested to know how it works.

Comment: @BumblingBadger I've added a brief explanation

Comment: @EdMorton OK thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is essentially [steeldriver's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684744/493832), reformulated as a single `awk` code block (in fact, as a single `print` statement):

```bsh
awk '{ print $1, ($2 in m) ? m[$2] : m[$2] = "user" ++n >(FILENAME ".anon") }' file[123]
```

The code uses the fact that the result of an assignment is the value that was assigned.

The associative array `m` contains a mapping between names and the anonymous `user` strings. For each record of two fields read from an input file, the first output field is reproduced as-is while the second field is picked from the value associated with the second input field used as a key in the `m` array. If no such key exists in `m`, a new `user` string is produced and stored in `m`.

Just like steeldriver decided to do, I write out the generated record to a new file named like the input file, with `.anon` added as a filename suffix.

If you want zero-filled numbers in the `user` strings, you could replace `m[$2] = "user" ++n` by e.g. `m[$2] = sprintf("user%.3d", ++n)`, which would give you the strings `user001` through to `user014` for the given data.